# Update to only one row even when query returns multiple

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I am new to psql and I am trying to update a table similar to below:

```
Command | Expected | Actual
show interfaces queue xe-1/1/2  | Queue: 0, Forwarding classes: CVX-Internet |
show interfaces queue xe-1/1/2  | Packets |
show interfaces queue xe-1/1/2  | Bytes |
show interfaces queue xe-1/1/2  | Queue: 1, Forwarding classes: CVX-VoIP |
show interfaces queue xe-1/1/2  | Packets |
show interfaces queue xe-1/1/2  | Bytes |
```

but when i say update:

```
UPDATE table SET Actual = 'Packets:10' WHERE Command = 'show interfaces queue xe-1/1/2' AND Expected = 'Packets';
```

It gets updated at 2 places.

I want a solution where I could hold the cursor at previous row and update respective next row containing 'packets' only when previous row contains value like 'Queue: 0'.
Please help.

Comment: Did you paste the wrong thing in as the table data? Because what you posted doesn't make any sense. I also think you'll need to explain your problem in a little more detail.

Comment: In a relational database there is no such thing as next/previous row, as the row order is undefined. If there is another meaningful ordering (e.g. timestamp) then that needs to be loaded into its own column, and then you can use that column to choose your row.

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Craig. I solved the problem by pasting respective 'Queue: ?' in front of the 'Packets' and 'Bytes' in Expected column so that I could now differentiate them and modified my UPDATE statement to "... AND Expected like 'Queue: 0, Packets'.